# golang check package dependencies on a single repository

Tags: go, package

I am working on a golang project which have a few packages (folders).  My purpose is to pull out a certain package into a separate module, but before I do this I want to see the package dependencies.  Is there any tool out there which I can run to view the package dependencies.  I am not talking about 3rd party modules but just simple folders in the same repo.  I checked around for a few tools but could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

`go list -f {{.Deps}} path/to/your/package` gives you all direct and indirect dependencies.

For Go modules you can do `go mod graph` or `go list -m all`.

Comment: thanks for this, it does help, but I need to know everything inside `path/to/your/package`, from what I saw it shows only for the packge given only, but I want to get everything inside `path/to/your/package` for example `path/to/your/package/subpackage1` and `path/to/your/package/subpackge2`

Comment: Have you tried `go list -f {{.Deps}} path/to/your/package/...`? I think the `...` will make it show multiple lists.